# How to repair torn vinyl flooring

Tags: repair, linoleum

Here is the problem:

[image: torn linoleum]

I'm renting the apartment and the tear wouldn't have happened if the flooring had been installed properly to begin with, so I'm not looking for perfection here. I just want my security deposit back when the time comes. I've read to warm the area with a hair dyer, smush it together as well as I can, use some kind of adhesive, then weight it for a day or so. Is there anything you'd like to add to that or dispute? Is there a particular grout or adhesive you'd recommend, particularly one likely to be available at Ace Hardware or Lowes?

Comment: Detail picture?  What kind of subfloor?  How did it rip?

Comment: How did it happen? HA! I went digging for a diamond earring that fell just where it managed to get under the vinyl at the gap under the (molding?). The stupid gap that shouldn't have been there anyway!

Answer (score 2):

First off that appears to be cheap PVC (Vinyl) sheet, not linoleum (linoleum is a natural product made from flax seed).  And the term 'grout' may set someone on the wrong path helping you.

Your faceless home store will have a variety of vinyl sheet goods glues and seam sealers for this purpose.  The seam sealer is probably the best bet as it comes in the smallest sizes, and you need just a tiny amount.

Dry it out first.  Open the windows, and get some heavy objects to keep it flat while the glue out-gasses and dries.  Use saran wrap to protect the heavy objects.

Comment: I'm sure you're right, whatever is the cheapest option is probably what I have. Opening the windows isn't an option (Alaska, remember) but I can use a fan. So seam sealer is what I should ask for, that's helpful.

Comment: Armstrong S-761 for example.  Everything else is in gallons and up at the home stores.

Comment: Definitely don't want a gallon!

Comment: For "doing it right" see http://www.thisoldhouse.com/toh/video/0,,20463936,00.html

Comment: Agree with @Bryce. When you go to get the seam sealer, take your picture with you to show them what you're trying to do. Sometimes they can give you some good advice too.